# Proving the existence of a weak limit given the convergence of $\lim_{n\to\infty}(x_n,v) \forall v\in H$

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, weak-convergence

I've got a problem I'm a little stuck on and was curious as to a way to prove this. I've always sort of just assumed that when defining weak convergence, the weak limit automatically exists but now I cant prove it. More formally, if for a sequence $\{x_n\}$ where $\lim_{n\to\infty}(v,x_n)$ exists for all $v\in H
$, prove that there exists an $x\in H$ such that
$\lim_{n\to\infty}(x_n,v)=(x,v)\quad \forall v\in H$.

My first approach was to consider the $\sup_{v\in H} \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{\Vert x_n\Vert} (x_n,\frac{v}{\Vert v\Vert})$ as something that would give me the weak limit $x$ that I desired, but after thinking about the case where $H=\ell^2$ and $x_n=e_n=(0,...,1,0,...)$ I'm uncertain, as $e_n\overset{w}{\to} 0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an immediate consequence of Uniform Boundedness Principle and Riesz Theorem. Let $T_n(v)=\langle v,x_n \rangle$. Then $T_n$ is a continuous linear functionsal on $H$ and $\sup_n |T_nv|<\infty$ for each $v$ because any convergent sequence of scalars is bounded. By Uniform Boundedness Principle we get $\sup_n \|T_n\| <\infty$. If we define $T(v)=\lim_{n \to \infty} \langle v,x_n \rangle$ then we get $\|T\| \leq \sup_n \|T_n\| <\infty$, so $T$ is a continuous linear functional. By Riesz THerem ther exists $x$ such that $Tv =\langle v, x \rangle$ for all $x$.

Comment: I had just used uniform boundedness on a previous part of this question but wasn't seeing this step. Thanks for your help!